# Multiple DIFFERENT CKeditor instances on the same page

Tags: ckeditor

I've made 2 custom builds of CKEditor for my CMS:

1. For general purposes
2. Just for creating of maps with Leaflet plugin

In general every page can consist of several "general" CKeditor blocks (and all is OK here). But some pages (like "Contacts", for example) can also contain "maps" instances. The instances are totally independent, it's not the same repo with different configs, it's 2 different builds. So I need to connect some textareas with the 1st build, and some with the 2nd. Is it possible?

Screenshots are attached below:

- [Folders with different repos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYSOw.png)
- [Maps editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPdzW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use different CKEditor builds on the same page. There's only a single CKEDITOR namespace, so there's no way to tell apart which build do you want to use.

Instead, you should use the extraPlugins and removePlugins config options to adjust each instance the way that you want.

Comment: Hmm... Can I change namespace of the 2nd instance to "CKEDITOR2", for example, using Search&Replace in the source files? If I really can not, I'll try to implement your solution, but it's not convenient because the functionality of the editors is totally different. Of cource I could use TinyMce or another WYSYWIG editor as a second instance, but I'd like to keep UI consistency, so using the same type of editor seems the most logical solution

Comment: You can try that approach, but using extraPlugins and removePlugins is really easy.